# iPhone, error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I know there's another question like this on stack overflow, but my problem is from my own class not a UIButton. My method is a lot more complicated. The first commented line works.

```
@implementation GettingStartedViewController
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

//[cui showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex:self.view:
  //theController:FALSE:HelpPageGettingStarted];

  // Error from this next line error: object cannot be set - either 
  //readonly property or no setter found 
  self.theController = [cui showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex:
      self.view:theController:FALSE:HelpPageGettingStarted];    
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad]; 
cui = [CommonUI alloc]; // Used for several functions
}
```

And heres the function it calls. I've trying to reuse code and keep things in one function. the function uses `addSubView` and `presentModalViewController`.

```
@implementation CommonUI
-(UIViewController *)showHelpClickButtonAtIndex:(int)buttonIndex:
  (UIView *)vw:(UIViewController *)vc:(BOOL)useNav:(HelpPage)page{

  if (buttonIndex == CommonUIInfoHelpPagesBtnIdx) {
    if (useNav == TRUE) {
        // snip
    } else {
        vc = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpView" 
             bundle:nil onPage:page];   
        [vw addSubview:vc.view];
        return [vc autorelease]; 
    }
  } else {
    // Snip
  }
// Snip
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message says that there is no property for `theController` in `GettingStartedViewController`. Your method call works just fine.

`self.theController = someObject` is the same as calling the setter method: `[self setTheController:someObject]`

Properties automatically generate those getters and setters; so if you did not define a property, it is not going to create a setter and this is your problem here.

Add the following to your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIViewController* theController;
```

And synthesize it in your implementation file:

```
@synthesize theController;
```

Do not forget to release it in the `-dealloc` method, as you told the setter to retain the object:

```
-(void) dealloc {
    [theController release];
    theController = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iPhone, error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found error comes when you have not synthesized it and still accessing its setter or/and getter method.

Comment: No. It says that there is no such setter. If there was a property defined that he forgot to synthesize, it would say `warning: property 'theController' requires method '-setTheController' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation`